# ServieConnection Not Working At All Android

Tags: android, service, connection

Good Day.I have the simplest scenario which could ever be!I have simple service connection which taken from google in app purchases example and this is my own code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
IInAppBillingService mService;
ServiceConnection mServiceConn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                       IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) {
        unbindService(mServiceConn);
    }
}
```

}
For first run it worked and it toasted.But afterwards it will never connect will never trigger onserviceconnected and onservicedisconnected.Doing researches in google i did not found any solution but only questions of familiar without any responsible answers.Thank you beforehand and please tell me what the heck to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call bind Service:

create intent and call bindService

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                    mService = null;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                               IBinder service) {
                    mService =   IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };

    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter("IntentFilterName");
    bindService(filter1, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```